# How to deploy Ruby (Sinatra Framework) using Apache with Puma on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, sinatra, puma

I am running an Ubuntu 22.04 server on Linode and trying to deploy a [simple Sinatra app](https://github.com/deis/example-ruby-sinatra) using Apache with Puma, but currently, I am only able to display the index page, so I believe I am missing a simple step. I'm not sure how to connect Puma to Apache, so there is probably something related to that that I am missing. Here are the key files:

/var/www/example.com/web.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

/var/www/example.com/config/puma.rb

```
workers 2
threads 5, 5

preload_app!

port        5000
environment 'development'
```

[/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin info@example.com
     ServerName sinatra.example.com

     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

     <Directory /var/www/example.com>
          DirectoryIndex web.rb
          Allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/errors.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sinatra.example.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have then run these commands without issue:

`bundle install`
`a2ensite`
`systemctl reload apache2`

Comment: I'm not well familiar with Apache, but as far as I see your virtual host config doesn't contain _any_ reverse proxy settings at all... Check [this article](https://learnwithdaniel.com/2015/01/apache-puma-via-reverse-proxy/), maybe it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a reverse proxy (as @konstantin-strukov mentioned). Here is the full list of files that I set up and the commands I ran (not including installing apache and ruby), so that there is no ambiguity.

**/var/www/example/web.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello World"
end
```

**/var/www/example/Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

**/var/www/example/GEMFILE**

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
ruby '3.0.4'
gem 'sinatra', '~>2'
gem 'puma', '~>5'
```

Note: Sinatra recently released a 3.0.0 version and Puma released a 6.0.0 and this caused conflicts with Rack, so I needed to use the previous version to get it to work.

**/var/www/example/config.ru**

```
require './web'
run Sinatra::Application
```

**/var/www/example/config/puma.rb**

```
workers 2
threads 1, 2

preload_app!

port        5000
environment "development"

app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
bind "unix://#{app_dir}/tmp/puma/puma.sock"
stdout_redirect "#{app_dir}/logs/puma.stdout.log", "#{app_dir}/logs/puma.stderr.log", true
pidfile "#{app_dir}/tmp/puma/pid"
state_path "#{app_dir}/tmp/puma/state"
directory "#{app_dir}/"
activate_control_app "unix://#{app_dir}/tmp/puma/pumactl.sock"
prune_bundler
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin info@example.com
     ServerName sinatra.example.com
     ProxyRequests Off
     <Proxy *>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
     </Proxy>
     ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
     ProxyVia On

     DocumentRoot /var/www/example

     <Directory /var/www/example>
          DirectoryIndex web.rb
          Allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog /var/www/example/logs/errors.log
     CustomLog /var/www/example/logs/access.log combined

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sinatra.example.com
     RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/systemd/system/puma.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server
After=network.target
Requires=puma.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/example
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/puma -C /var/www/example/config/puma.rb
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/systemd/system/puma.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server Accept Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:5000

# Socket options matching Puma defaults
NoDelay=true
ReusePort=true
Backlog=1024

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

1. cd /var/www/example
2. bundle install
3. mkdir /var/www/example/logs
4. mkdir /var/www/example/tmp
5. mkdir /var/www/example/tmp/puma
6. chmod 777 /var/www/example/logs
7. chmod 755 /var/www/example/tmp
8. chmod 755 /var/www/example/tmp/puma
9. a2ensite example
10. a2enmod

    proxy proxy_ajp proxy_http rewrite deflate headers proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_html
11. systemctl daemon-reload
12. systemctl enable puma.service
13. systemctl enable puma.socket
14. systemctl start puma.socket
15. systemctl start puma.service
16. systemctl reload apache2